# woo-commerce add to cart via category page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to know the best/quickest options for implementing **bulk adding products to a woo-commerce cart** through the category page (without actually having to view the individual item to add it to the cart).

I am happy to hook into the code somewhere but I would prefer the use of the plugin or theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This plugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/add-multiple-products-to-cart-in-woocommerce/8283360) looks like it'll get the job done for you.  It adds check boxes to the shop pages so you can select multiple items at once and add them all together, and it includes a "select all" option, so if you were looking at a category page you could select all and then add.

Not sure how it would handle categories with multiple pages, or if it even would.  If you need something more custom you could build your own plugin and hook in to WC like you mentioned.